# Well-founded part of integer numbers

Tags: relations, well-orders

Peter Aczel writes in his [An Introduction to Inductive Definitions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0049237X08711200):

> Let $\prec$ be a binary relation on a set $A$. The well-founded part of $\prec$ is the set $W(\prec)$ of $a\in A$ such that there is no infinite descending sequence $a\succ a_0\succ a_1\succ\ldots$ .

Am I right that if I take $\mathbb{Z}$, the set of integers with the usual less-than relation, then the well-founded part of it, $W(\prec)$ is the empty set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - for any integer $z$, consider the sequence $$z>z-1>z-2>z-3>...$$

By contrast, the well-founded part of $\mathbb{N}$ (with the usual ordering) is exactly all of $\mathbb{N}$ - this is equivalent, in a precise sense, to [proof by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) being valid!

As a third example - between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ - consider the set of real numbers which are either $> 1$ or are of the form $1-{1\over n}$ for some nonzero natural number $n$. Then the well-founded part of this set (ordered in the usual way) is exactly $$\{1-{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$